# Tweepy lookup of extended tweets for multiple tweets at a time?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to access a large number of tweets. Many tweets are truncated, so I want to get the full text of some tweets, which I have the id for.

My problem is: The tweepy api instance has one method of downloading multiple tweets at once (api.statuses_lookup), but this returns truncated tweets.
It also has a method that includes the full tweet text (api.get_status), but which afaik only takes one tweet at a time.
Is there way of getting the full text for multiple tweets at once?

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "XXX"
secret = "XXX"
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, secret)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

ids =  [1108360183586140161, 1108474125486641153]

# Finds tweets (up to 100 at a time), but doesn't contain extended text
foo = api.statuses_lookup(ids)

# Returns tweet, including extended text, but only for one at a time
bar = api.get_status(1108449077937635328, tweet_mode='extended')
```

Comment: are you saying that api.statuses_lookup does not also support the tweet_mode parameter?

Comment: Correct. Trying that gives: statuses_lookup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tweet_mode'

Comment: Looks like you need version 3.7.0 or better https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/840

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'll add an answer in case it's helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Andy Piper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262478/andy-piper), the issue was fixed in a recent update of the Tweepy library, so running

```
pip install tweepy --upgrade
```

solves this.